# Generating random number between 1 and 10 in Bash Shell Script

Tags: bash

How would I generate an inclusive random number between  1 to 10 in Bash Shell Script?

Would it be `$(RANDOM 1+10)`?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

Comment: this works for what I need `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$((( RANDOM % 8 )))`

Answer (score 386, accepted):

```
$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
```

**EDIT.** Changed brackets into parenthesis according to the comment.
http://web.archive.org/web/20150206070451/http://islandlinux.org/howto/generate-random-numbers-bash-scripting

Comment: I get a syntax error: syntax error near unexpected token `+' on Linux

Comment: The `% 10` reduces the result to a set of ranges from 0-9.  However, the very top set only has a range of 0-7.  Thus, there are two fewer draws for 8 & 9 than 0-7.  The + 1 translates this to a bias against 9 & 10.  This would be a major flaw in security contexts - an RNG must not display bias, and at scale this is noticeable.  Further explanation: [Anatomy of a pseudorandom number generator - visualising Cryptocat's buggy PRNG](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/07/09/anatomy-of-a-pseudorandom-number-generator-visualising-cryptocats-buggy-prng/).

Comment: @BradKoch How do we know that Bash's RNG makes that error?

Comment: @ads20000 The docs say so, `man bash`, "Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated."  Note that this is not a bash error, it's an error of the implementer.  Assuming bash implemented `$RANDOM` correctly, there should be a fair draw from numbers 0 to 32767, but because you can't divide that evenly into groups of 10, there is a very small bias against 9 and 10 in this implementation.  Most people shouldn't need to worry about this, because you shouldn't be using `$RANDOM` for security purposes anyway.

Comment: By far the simplest solution

Comment: this works for what I need `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$((( RANDOM % 8 )))`

Comment: `$(( ( RANDOM % ($MAX_RANDOM_NUM - $MIN_RANDOM_NUM + 1)) + $MIN_RANDOM_NUM ))`

Answer (score 116):

Simplest solution would be to use tool which allows you to directly specify ranges, like [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu) `shuf`

```
shuf -i1-10 -n1
```

If you want to use `$RANDOM`, it would be more precise to throw out the last 8 numbers in 0...32767, and just treat it as 0...32759, since taking 0...32767 mod 10 you get the following distribution

```
0-8 each: 3277 
8-9 each: 3276
```

So, slightly slower but more precise would be

```
while :; do ran=$RANDOM; ((ran < 32760)) && echo $(((ran%10)+1)) && break; done
```

Comment: I found this question looking for `/bin/sh` even though the question requests bash. The `shuf` technique appears to work in both bash and sh.

Answer (score 44):

To generate random numbers with bash use the $RANDOM internal Bash function. Note that $RANDOM should not be used to generate an encryption key. $RANDOM is generated by using your current process ID (PID) and the current time/date as defined by the number of seconds elapsed since 1970.

```
 echo $RANDOM % 10 + 1 | bc
```

Comment: I found $RANDOM cannot generate big number, so I use `date +%s` to get a big number.  `echo $(date +%s) % 4 | bc`

Comment: What does the "| bc" part do?

Comment: @ebi `echo` just prints the string (variable substitution happens before the command is processed, so `$RANDOM` is already replaced with an integer by that point), `bc` is what actually evaluates it when the `|` redirects the stdout from the `echo` into the stdin of the `bc`

Comment: Works well on Mac OS X. +1

Answer (score 32):

You can also use /dev/urandom:

```
grep -m1 -ao '[0-9]' /dev/urandom | sed s/0/10/ | head -n1
```

Comment: Useful when you don't have $RANDOM available, i.e. busybox

Comment: clever trick `sed s/0/10/` !

Answer (score 25):

To generate in the range: {0,..,9}

`r=$(( $RANDOM % 10 )); echo $r`

To generate in the range: {40,..,49}

`r=$(( $RANDOM % 10 + 40 )); echo $r`

Answer (score -6):

Here is example of pseudo-random generator when neither $RANDOM nor /dev/urandom is available

> echo $(date +%S) | grep -o .$ |  sed s/0/10/

Comment: It just prints an increasing sequence of numbers every time I run it: "1... 2... 3.... 4..." basically, the least-significant digit of the current second.

Comment: A date is not random at all. It is completely predictable and follows an obvious pattern.