# Function to produce random number between 0 to 50

Tags: linux, bash, function

Below is the code i thought would create a random number between 0 to 50(Both included)

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=51
var=$RANDOM
echo $var
function rand(){
    local var1=$1
    local var2=$2
    local result=$(( var1 % var2 ))
    echo $result
}   
rand "var" "var1"
```

The first echo function is working fine its is showing a random number every time but the other echo function is always giving an output of zero

Comment: See [Random number from a range in a Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2556190/4154375) and [Generating random number between 1 and 10 in Bash Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988824/4154375).  Also see [BashFAQ/026 (How can I randomize/shuffle the order of lines in a file? ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026), particularly the implementions of the `rand` function.

Answer (score 1):

> Function to produce random number between 0 to 50

The function:

```
rand() { echo $((RANDOM % 50)); }
```

To your code:

- bash uses strings
- `rand "var" "var1"` pases string `var` and string `var1` to the function
- then `local var1=$1` set's the variable `var1` to be a local variable and the value of the `var1` variable is the `var` *string*(!).
- then `local var2=$2` is equal to `local var2="var1"`, it set's `var2` variable value to the *string* "var1".
- `local result=$(( var1 % var2 ))` is invalid. This is equal to `local result=$(( "var" % "var1" ))`. You can't do calculus over "strings", it's meaningless.
- Just pass the values of the variables `rand "$var" "$var1"` to the function.

Comment: Can we pass integers to functions in bash

Comment: There are no integers, per se. There are strings. An "integer" is a string (ie. it's representation in base 10). `var1=1` set's var1 to the string 1. When you do arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` then shell converts strings into numbers, does the arithmetic, and then converts number back to the string, to it's representation in base 10. You can "expand" the variable using `$`, ie. get it's value, ie.  `rand "$var" "$var1"`. Please read online resources on that topic, ex. [this](https://www.shellscript.sh/variables1.html).

Comment: I admit to not diving into the bash source to see how this is implemented, but you can give a variable an integer "attribute": `declare -i var`. Then if you try to assign a non-integer value to it, it just gets zero assigned instead.